# Nested Directives and NgModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I feel like I'm missing a fundamental concept of Angular directives.

Referring to this Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/WWp9lB6OvxHL8gyBSU5b?p=preview

I have a model of:

```
{
  message: string,
  value: number
}
```

And I have an itemEditor directive to edit that model:

```
  .directive('itemEditor', function() {
    return {
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'item.editor.html',
      require: 'ngModel',
      model: {
        item: '=ngModel'
      }
    };
  })
```

But I want to delegate the editing of value to a custom control:

```
.directive('valuePicker', function() {
    return {
      replace: true, // comment this to make it work
      templateUrl: 'value.picker.html',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      },

      controller: Controller
    };

    function Controller($scope, Values) {
      $scope.values = Values;
      console.log({scope:$scope});
    }

  })
```

At current, this code gives the error:

```
Error: $compile:multidir
Multiple Directive Resource Contention
```

Commenting the *replace: true* will allow this code to work.  However, I lose the styling instructions from the parent template.  I.E: the class *form-control* is not merged onto the select element.

What is the angular way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `value-picker` twice here

```
<value-picker class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="item" value-picker ng-model="item.value"></value-picker>
```

The `value-picker` element contains `value-picker` attribute as well, both being treated as directive which in conflict causing multiple directive error. Remove the attribute `value-picker`, either call it as element or attribute. Or you can [`restrict`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-restrict-) the directive to a specific declaration.

Also remove `ng-model` from `select` element of `value.picker.html` template, which is causing another error:

> Multiple directives [ngModel, ngModel] asking for 'ngModel'

So `replace: true` replaces and appends the current directive attributes to the root level of template element (in your case its `select`)

[Updated Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UFWmCpPNL42yig497HKC)

Comment: ah.. I see. So, ng-model gets merged into the template as well.  Excellent. Thank you much!